# Macro to verify when file was modified last time

Tags: excel, vba, file, date

I have seen some pretty similar questions but none of them have the answer I was looking for. Some of them wasn't answered.

I have a VBA Macro which verify all files created in a certain date (in this case yesterday) by searching for the files and verifying when the file was created. As the macro was found in the internet, I am not sure how the objects work.

I was wondering if there is a way to change the fill.DateCreated for something similar but instead of checking the Date when the file was created, the macro would verify when the file was modified. It appeared to be simple at first, but now I am really struggling to get this. Can anyone help me with this?

```
Sub VerifyNewFiles()

Dim n As String, msg As String, d As Date
msg = ""
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fils = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Desktop\").Files

For Each fil In fils
    n = fil.Name
    d = fil.DateCreated

    If d >= Date - 1 Then
        msg = msg & n & vbTab & d & vbCrLf
    End If
Next fil

MsgBox msg

Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f.DateLastModified` would probably do for you.

If you add references to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` library via Tools -> References in VBE you can early bind your objects and get intelli-sense with them.

```
Sub VerifyNewFiles()

    Dim fName As String, msg As String, fDate As Date


    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Set fils = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\Desktop\").Files

    Dim fil As File
    For Each fil In fils

        fName = fil.Name
        fDate = fil.DateLastModified

        If fDate >= Date - 1 Then msg = msg & fName & vbTab & fDate & vbCrLf
    Next fil

    MsgBox msg

    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Having library references (Microsoft Scripting Runtime) added to you project you can open up Object Browser <kbd>F2</kbd> and select the library to explore it

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you should use the DateLastModified property on the fil object within your for each loop. So this:

```
d = fil.DateCreated
```

Would become this:

```
d = fil.DateLastModified
```

I suggest you look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251660(v=office.15).aspx) for more information on the DateLastModified property.